# File.WriteAllLines not working in C# (Visual Studio 19)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file

I am making a program in c#. I am trying to access a file (named `counter.txt`, in the `Logs` folder) using C#'s `File` class. I am reading the file, storing the only line in a variable named `count`, I increase it by 1, and then I write it back into the file. The reading and incrementation work, but the writing doesn't. I've tried to use different datatypes for the output container (`string[]`, `List<string>`, ...). Nothing works. I am following a tutorial, and the code works fine there. I suppose it is a Visual Studio 19 or an antivirus/permission issue? Here is the code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Program
{
    class Logger
    {

        private int count = 0;

        // setup
        public void Start()
        {
            string counterFile = @".\\Logs\\counter.txt";

            string line = File.ReadAllLines(counterFile)[0];
            count = int.Parse(line);
            count++;
            string[] toWrite = {count.ToString()};
            Console.WriteLine(counterFile);
            File.WriteAllLines(counterFile, toWrite);
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
```

The file structure (Logger.cs is the file I'm doing this in):
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sesions; this conversation has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226381/discussion-on-question-by-cpppythondude-file-writealllines-not-working-in-c-vi). If you are asked for more details, please [edit] the information into your question, rather than replying in comments.

Comment: (It would be nice if the "Move to chat" button appeared earlier: it doesn't seem to pop up when multiple people are involved, meaning that comments are the only place to carry out the debugging needed to get enough details to provide an answer)

Answer (score 0):

As identified in the comments, the problem is that you've added `counter.txt` to Visual Studio, with a "Copy to output directory" property of "Always".

This means that whenever you build your project, Visual Studio will copy that `counter.txt` to your `bin` directory, overwriting whatever file was there before.

Your application is, of course, modifying the copy in the `bin` directory.

A better approach would be to remove `counter.txt` from your file list in Visual Studio entirely, and instead all logic to your problem to create the file if it doesn't already exist. Something like:

```
class Logger
{

    private int count = 0;

    // setup
    public void Start()
    {
        string counterDirectory = "Logs";
        string counterFile = Path.Join(counterDirectory, "counter.txt");

        if (!Directory.Exists(counterDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(counterDirectory);
        }

        if (File.Exists(counterFile))
        {  
            string line = File.ReadAllLines(counterFile)[0];
            count = int.Parse(line);
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            count = 1;
        }

        string[] toWrite = {count.ToString()};
        Console.WriteLine(counterFile);

        File.WriteAllLines(counterFile, toWrite);
        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
}
```

---

Another problem you are going to run into at some point is that the path to your file is relative, and therefore relative to the user's current working directory.

This might be the directory containing your application, but it might not be: try opening a command prompt inside your `bin` folder and then running `Debug\YourApplication.exe`, and see that `Logs` is created in your current directory!

Instead, you probably want to do something like:

```
class Logger
{

    private int count = 0;

    // setup
    public void Start()
    {
        string applicationDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Logger).Assembly.Location);
        string counterDirectory = Path.Join(applicationDirectory , "Logs");
        string counterFile = Path.Join(counterDirectory, "counter.txt");

        if (!Directory.Exists(counterDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(counterDirectory);
        }

        if (File.Exists(counterFile))
        {  
            string line = File.ReadAllLines(counterFile)[0];
            count = int.Parse(line);
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            count = 1;
        }

        string[] toWrite = {count.ToString()};
        Console.WriteLine(counterFile);

        File.WriteAllLines(counterFile, toWrite);
        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
}
```

---

Also your code to read/write the file is overly complex: there's no need to use arrays here, as the file only contains a single line! You can get away with something like:

```
class Logger
{

    private int count = 0;

    // setup
    public void Start()
    {
        string applicationDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Logger).Assembly.Location);
        string counterDirectory = Path.Join(applicationDirectory , "Logs");
        string counterFile = Path.Join(counterDirectory, "counter.txt");

        if (!Directory.Exists(counterDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(counterDirectory);
        }

        if (File.Exists(counterFile))
        {  
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(counterFile);
            count = int.Parse(contents);
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            count = 1;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(counterFile);

        File.WriteAllText(counterFile, count.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Happy for you to answer -- you did a good chunk of the digging! I've deliberately focussed just on the suggestion I made, so there's scope for your answer with more details on the problem, and your suggestion about "Copy if newer". Yeah I'm doing a series of edits with improvements

Answer (score -1):

Your code works just fine if the path to the file is correct and your app is able to access that folder, the file is not locked, etc.

I was trying this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count;
            string counterFile = @"D:\tmp\counter.txt";

            string line = File.ReadAllLines(counterFile)[0];
            count = int.Parse(line);
            count++;
            string[] toWrite = { count.ToString() };
            Console.WriteLine(counterFile);
            File.WriteAllLines(counterFile, toWrite);
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
```

With the file containing 5. Here is the result:
[image]

The updated file looks like:
[image]

Update. You have to check that your file is copied on build. That's might be your issue

Comment: The console output works just fine. The file is not getting changed, though. I want to keep a track of the count (stored in the counter.txt file) between multiple runs of the program.

Comment: You shall not mess with the file in your project and the file in the output folder.

Comment: @CppPythonDude, does it solve your problem?